# ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender drag issue

Tags: popup, drag, modalpopupextender

When I try to drag the popup, first I have to click on draging position. But when I try to click on the draging enable area, popup window goes to another position. Even I try again it continuously happens.

here is my mark up:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnEditAddress"
        PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnOKAddress"
        CancelControlID="btnCancelAddress" DropShadow="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="headHolder"
        X="270" Y="130" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="width: 320px;
        display: none;">
        <div>
            <div id="headHolder" runat="server" class="addressEditHead" style="height: 20px;
                padding-top: 5px;">
                <span style="padding-left: 5px;" id="addressType" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 25px; text-align: center;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnOKAddress" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" OnClientClick="saveAddress();" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelAddress" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancel" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRelatedTable" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRelatedID" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**Hi, All I found the solution. I upgrade the ajaxtoolkit to latest version. Now It's working coreclty**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I upgraded the ajaxtoolkit to latest version. Now It's working coreclty.